# I can not call jquery plugin function outside of plugin code

Tags: jquery, function, plugins, call, tiptip

This is my definition

```
$(".HideOnClick").live({ click: function () { deactive_tiptip() } });
```

This is how i am calling it inside title of html elements

```
<a href=# class=HideOnClick>Close Me</a>
```

This is how i add the TipTip plugin to my content

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.monstermmorpg.com/js_files/jquery_1_6_2_min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.monstermmorpg.com/js_files/jquery_tipTip_minified.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

But it gives function undefined error. Plugin is working perfectly.

This is the plugin source code

```
 /*
 * TipTip
 * Copyright 2010 Drew Wilson
 * www.drewwilson.com
 * code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin
 *
 * Version 1.3   -   Updated: Mar. 23, 2010
 *
 * This Plug-In will create a custom tooltip to replace the default
 * browser tooltip. It is extremely lightweight and very smart in
 * that it detects the edges of the browser window and will make sure
 * the tooltip stays within the current window size. As a result the
 * tooltip will adjust itself to be displayed above, below, to the left 
 * or to the right depending on what is necessary to stay within the
 * browser window. It is completely customizable as well via CSS.
 *
 * This TipTip jQuery plug-in is dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 */

(function($){
    $.fn.tipTip = function(options) {
        var defaults = { 
            activation: "hover",
            keepAlive: false,
            sticky: false,
            maxWidth: "200px",
            edgeOffset: 3,
            defaultPosition: "bottom",
            delay: 400,
            fadeIn: 200,
            fadeOut: 200,
            attribute: "title",
            content: false, // HTML or String to fill TipTIp with
            enter: function(){},
            exit: function(){}
        };
        var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

        // Setup tip tip elements and render them to the DOM
        if($("#tiptip_holder").length <= 0){
            var tiptip_holder = $('<div id="tiptip_holder" style="max-width:'+ opts.maxWidth +';"></div>');
            var tiptip_content = $('<div id="tiptip_content"></div>');
            var tiptip_arrow = $('<div id="tiptip_arrow"></div>');
            $("body").append(tiptip_holder.html(tiptip_content).prepend(tiptip_arrow.html('<div id="tiptip_arrow_inner"></div>')));
        } else {
            var tiptip_holder = $("#tiptip_holder");
            var tiptip_content = $("#tiptip_content");
            var tiptip_arrow = $("#tiptip_arrow");
        }

        return this.each(function(){
            var org_elem = $(this);
            if(opts.content){
                var org_title = opts.content;
            } else {
                var org_title = org_elem.attr(opts.attribute);
            }
            if(org_title != ""){
                if(!opts.content){
                    org_elem.removeAttr(opts.attribute); //remove original Attribute
                }
                var timeout = false;

                if(opts.activation == "hover"){
                    org_elem.hover(function(){
                        active_tiptip();
                    }, function(){
                        if(!opts.keepAlive){
                            deactive_tiptip();
                        }
                    });
                    if(opts.keepAlive){
                        tiptip_holder.hover(function(){}, function(){

                        });
                    }
                } else if(opts.activation == "focus"){
                    org_elem.focus(function(){
                        active_tiptip();
                    }).blur(function(){
                        deactive_tiptip();
                    });
                } else if(opts.activation == "click"){
                    org_elem.click(function(){
                        active_tiptip();
                        return false;
                    }).hover(function(){},function(){
                        if(!opts.keepAlive){
                            deactive_tiptip();
                        }
                    });
                    if(opts.keepAlive){
                        tiptip_holder.hover(function(){}, function(){

                        });
                    }
                }

                function active_tiptip(){
                    opts.enter.call(this);
                    tiptip_content.html(org_title);
                    tiptip_holder.hide().removeAttr("class").css("margin","0");
                    tiptip_arrow.removeAttr("style");

                    var top = parseInt(org_elem.offset()['top']);
                    var left = parseInt(org_elem.offset()['left']);
                    var org_width = parseInt(org_elem.outerWidth());
                    var org_height = parseInt(org_elem.outerHeight());
                    var tip_w = tiptip_holder.outerWidth();
                    var tip_h = tiptip_holder.outerHeight();
                    var w_compare = Math.round((org_width - tip_w) / 2);
                    var h_compare = Math.round((org_height - tip_h) / 2);
                    var marg_left = Math.round(left + w_compare);
                    var marg_top = Math.round(top + org_height + opts.edgeOffset);
                    var t_class = "";
                    var arrow_top = "";
                    var arrow_left = Math.round(tip_w - 12) / 2;

                    if(opts.defaultPosition == "bottom"){
                        t_class = "_bottom";
                    } else if(opts.defaultPosition == "top"){ 
                        t_class = "_top";
                    } else if(opts.defaultPosition == "left"){
                        t_class = "_left";
                    } else if(opts.defaultPosition == "right"){
                        t_class = "_right";
                    }

                    var right_compare = (w_compare + left) < parseInt($(window).scrollLeft());
                    var left_compare = (tip_w + left) > parseInt($(window).width());

                    if((right_compare && w_compare < 0) || (t_class == "_right" && !left_compare) || (t_class == "_left" && left < (tip_w + opts.edgeOffset + 5))){
                        t_class = "_right";
                        arrow_top = Math.round(tip_h - 13) / 2;
                        arrow_left = -12;
                        marg_left = Math.round(left + org_width + opts.edgeOffset);
                        marg_top = Math.round(top + h_compare);
                    } else if((left_compare && w_compare < 0) || (t_class == "_left" && !right_compare)){
                        t_class = "_left";
                        arrow_top = Math.round(tip_h - 13) / 2;
                        arrow_left =  Math.round(tip_w);
                        marg_left = Math.round(left - (tip_w + opts.edgeOffset + 5));
                        marg_top = Math.round(top + h_compare);
                    }

                    var top_compare = (top + org_height + opts.edgeOffset + tip_h + 8) > parseInt($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop());
                    var bottom_compare = ((top + org_height) - (opts.edgeOffset + tip_h + 8)) < 0;

                    if(top_compare || (t_class == "_bottom" && top_compare) || (t_class == "_top" && !bottom_compare)){
                        if(t_class == "_top" || t_class == "_bottom"){
                            t_class = "_top";
                        } else {
                            t_class = t_class+"_top";
                        }
                        arrow_top = tip_h;
                        marg_top = Math.round(top - (tip_h + 5 + opts.edgeOffset));
                    } else if(bottom_compare | (t_class == "_top" && bottom_compare) || (t_class == "_bottom" && !top_compare)){
                        if(t_class == "_top" || t_class == "_bottom"){
                            t_class = "_bottom";
                        } else {
                            t_class = t_class+"_bottom";
                        }
                        arrow_top = -12;                        
                        marg_top = Math.round(top + org_height + opts.edgeOffset);
                    }

                    if(t_class == "_right_top" || t_class == "_left_top"){
                        marg_top = marg_top + 5;
                    } else if(t_class == "_right_bottom" || t_class == "_left_bottom"){     
                        marg_top = marg_top - 5;
                    }
                    if(t_class == "_left_top" || t_class == "_left_bottom"){    
                        marg_left = marg_left + 5;
                    }
                    tiptip_arrow.css({"margin-left": arrow_left+"px", "margin-top": arrow_top+"px"});
                    tiptip_holder.css({"margin-left": marg_left+"px", "margin-top": marg_top+"px"}).attr("class","tip"+t_class);

                    if (timeout){ clearTimeout(timeout); }
                    timeout = setTimeout(function(){ tiptip_holder.stop(true,true).fadeIn(opts.fadeIn); }, opts.delay); 
                }

                function deactive_tiptip(){
                    opts.exit.call(this);
                    if (timeout){ clearTimeout(timeout); }
                    tiptip_holder.fadeOut(opts.fadeOut);
                }
            }               
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I am calling functions like this and they are working

```
   <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".KeepAlive").tipTip({ fadeIn: 25, fadeOut: 25, delay: "25", maxWidth: "300px", edgeOffset: 5, keepAlive: true, activation: "click", defaultPosition: "right", exit: function () { } });
            $(".ShowTitle").tipTip({ fadeIn: 25, fadeOut: 25, delay: "25", maxWidth: "300px", edgeOffset: 5, keepAlive: true, defaultPosition: "right" });
            $(".HideOnClick").live('click', function () {
                deactive_tiptip();
            });
        });

        function pageLoad() {

            if (Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {

                $(".KeepAlive").tipTip({ fadeIn: 25, fadeOut: 25, delay: "25", maxWidth: "300px", edgeOffset: 5, keepAlive: true, activation: "click", defaultPosition: "right" });
                $(".ShowTitle").tipTip({ fadeIn: 25, fadeOut: 25, delay: "25", maxWidth: "300px", edgeOffset: 5, keepAlive: true, defaultPosition: "right" });
                $('body').css('cursor', 'default');

            }
        }
```

```
 kT.Style.Value = srOtherPlayerImagesLeftValues[i] + " " + srOtherPlayerImagesTopValues[i] + " ";
                                lbUImg.Text = " <img  class=\"KeepAlive\"  src=\"" + 
                                    "http://static.monstermmorpg.com/images/userImages/trainer" + dsOtherUsers.Tables[0].Rows[i]["charImage"].ToString() +  
                                    dsOtherUsers.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Direction"].ToString() + ".png\"" +
                                   " title='İsim: "+ dsOtherUsers.Tables[0].Rows[i]["userName"].ToString() +
                                     "<hr/>" +
                                    "<a href=http://www.monstermmorpg.com/PVPBattleOffer.aspx?UserName=" + dsOtherUsers.Tables[0].Rows[i]["userName"].ToString() 
                                    +" target=_blank class=linkUserMap>PVP Savaşı Teklif Et</a><hr/>" +
                                "<a href=http://www.monstermmorpg.com/SeeUserProfile.aspx?PlayerName=" + dsOtherUsers.Tables[0].Rows[i]["userName"].ToString()
                                + " target=_blank class=linkUserMap>Profilini Göster</a><hr/> <a href=# class=HideOnClick>Close Me</a>  '\"/>";
```

Comment: The problem is that `deactive_tiptip` isn't an exposed function, not in the scope you're trying to use it in. Can you show how you're calling `whatever.tipTip ()` to bind to the elements?

Comment: alright i updated main question check from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `deactive_tiptip` isn't an exposed function, not in the scope you're trying to use it in.  Instead, you can * normally* trigger it with the same event on to "exit"....but since you're using `keepAlive: true` that won't work either.

You could instead (since it isn't exposed) just do what the plugin does internally, like this:

```
$(".HideOnClick").live({ 
  click: function () { $("#tiptip_holder").fadeOut(); }
});
```

Not however, this won't call your defined `exit` function, but since the only one you have is a no-op, this should be fine.

Also, if you want it a bit more efficient, go for delegate, something like this:

```
$(document).delegate(".HideOnClick", "click", function () {
  $("#tiptip_holder").fadeOut(); 
});
```

...this doesn't incur the initial `$(".HideOnClick")` selector cost for no reason.

Comment: i can remove keep alive. please explain that way thank you. and this is working right now but i can remove keep alive because i am trying to make sticky tooltip

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - If you remove keep alive, it'll just close on any click, so that's probably not what you're after...I'd just go with this route, short of changing the plugin itself to allow a "close" event you can trigger...that is an option, just not great if you refresh/upgrade your plugins often (unless you contact the author to include the enhancement).

Comment: how can i change the plugin that way ? seems like plugin owner is not supporting it any longer and i couldn't find any other cool tooltip plugin working as easy as this one. If you help me i really appreciate it.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/s7v6f/ note the 3 lines added with: `org_elem.bind("tiptip-close", function() { deactivate_titip(); });`, you can just use it like this: `$(document).delegate(".HideOnClick", "click", function () {
  $(this).trigger("tiptip-close");
});` and it'll trigger the handler the plugin has attached...no conditionals on anything, it'll always close it.

Comment: very interesting but not working :( Does not give any error etc . I looked from dynamic view via debug and doesn't enter the inside binding tiptip-close

Comment: i am calling it like this inside title  <a href=# class=HideOnClick>Close Me</a>

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Isn't the correct syntax for `live()`:</strike>

<strike>$(".HideOnClick").live('click', function() {
        deactive_tiptip();
    });</strike>

Also you might want to look into `delegate()`.

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

It's better performance wise.

**EDIT**

The function you try to call isn't in the scope of where you call it (e.g. it is in the plugin).

You cannot access it directly from outside the plugin.

I also wouldn't be possible because the plugin does some stuff before the function is called in the plugin with data the function uses

**EDIT 2**

From the TipTip docs:

> activation: string ("hover" by default) - jQuery method TipTip is activated with. Can be set to: "hover", "focus" or "click".

Don't think you can do exactly dwhat you want, consider the fact that the plugin has no `deactivation` settings. But perhaps you can extend the functionality to add a `deactivation` option.

Comment: But a lot more annoying and harder to implement (i.e. event targets). Still worth the effort though.

Comment: The OP's syntax is correct, he's using the `.live(events)` map overload: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Gave error again. Please i really need to solve this. I don't know jquery actually :D   the error message : Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'deactive_tiptip' is undefined

Comment: @Nick: OK didn't know that. Thanks. @OP: is the `deactive_tiptip()` function defined when you try to call it? If it is a different .js file make sure it si included on the page before the file with the call

Comment: It is defined at here   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.monstermmorpg.com/js_files/jquery_tipTip_minified.js"></script>   could you please take a look at source code . i also included it to the first message

Comment: i don't see any answer here. you are telling me why won't work instead of how to make it work.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: I have told you probably can extend the functionality of the plugin. That would be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this error is happening when you actually call the `$(".HideOnClick")...` code.

It looks like your code doesn't yet know about the jQuery library. Things to try:

1. Ensure your script is block is declared after the two library includes
2. Ensure your script is placed in a `$(document).ready()` handler.

Comment: they are ensured. plugin is working. i am clicking after everything loaded like this. let me show you screenshot   http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/7895/prolemimage.png